# Convert asp.net website to Sharepoint Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have my asp.net web application already build and working on IIS.
But my client wants to deploy that site into SharePoint environment.
So which is best way to convert to SharePoint website?

I have created one Virtual directory inside application created into IIS and its working fine but client wants to maintain whole site from SharePoint server only.

What is the best solution for it?

Comment: Sounds like your client should have mentioned the requirement of using SharePoint in the beginning, before you started working on the ASP.NET site.

Comment: does the customer want to create a sharepoint application, or does he simply want to spare a server, and reuse the sharepoint server? Making SharePoint and the ASP.Net webapp working side by side?

Comment: @JasonEvans Yes they have mentioned it but we are not aware what exactly SharePoint is so what we have done is that let's create site in asp.net and at that time we thought that we will see how to deploy it to SharePoint. but currently we are facing this problem.

Comment: @SteveB Yes they want to create a SharePoint application

Comment: While it can technically works to build "classic" ASP.Net application within SharePoint, I strongly advise you to build an actual SharePoint application. This may be a bit difficult to change, but if you don't, you'll end up with many problems related to this Frakenstein application. @JasonEvans is right... the customer should have mentioned it at the beginning. This implies structural and design consideration. Finally, do not hesitate to visit the [SharePoint dedicated Stackexchange site](http://sharepoint.Stackexchange.com) for any sharepoint question.

Answer (score 0):

Open your website in Visual studio **2013**, right click on web application. In convert options select "Convert to App for SharePoint Project". After conversion you will be able to deploy this solution to SharePoint sites.

Comment: Thank you so much but it only supports .net framework 4.0 or higher but my application is in .net framework 3.5